# SSRS 2012 windows file share schedule method of delivery not available

Tags: subscription, ssrs-2012

I am recently unable to select "Windows file share" as a method of report delivery in SSRS 2012 report manager, subscriptions section of report properties.

There is now only 1 option - "E-mail".

I have previously been able to select this option and have set up subscriptions to use windows file share. These subscriptions continue to work and are producing the files as desired. When

I look at the subscription properties for reports I have already set up, none of the widows file share properties text boxes are there to edit, just the schedule time and the method of delivery combobox (with email as the only option).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If I need to provide further information, please ask. I have provided as much as I thought pertinent to the issue. I have not been able to find any information to even hint at the issue so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the ReportingServices.config. Someone had put in the 'chrome fix' which was either incorrectly formatted or just plain wrong.

I'm afraid I don't have access to the server to paste the code here, so can be nothing bu vague.

A strange error with no real symptoms. It was fixed by a lot of trial an error digging - we compared the config to a default version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure an unattended execution account has been configured. Go into the Reporting Services Configuration Manager on the report server and set up the account there and restart the service.